# Who are we: "Come and see!"

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> We sicken at the thought of history.
>
> We fight to make our mark on the present.
>
> We hunger to deprive the future.
>
> We end everything because it is our nature.

**Who are we?**

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Nice first riddle. +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are:

> The Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse

We sicken at the thought of history.

> Pestilence or Pollution

We fight to make our mark on the present.

> War

We hunger to deprive the future.

> Famine

We end everything because it is our nature.

> Death

The title is also a hint:

> " Come and See" is the phrase used to summon the Four Horsemen to the Apocalypse in the novel 'Good Omens' by Neil Gaiman and Terry Pratchett. If you have not read it, do yourself a favour and get a copy NOW.

Comment: You nailed it! "Come and See!" is also what all of the horsemen said in Revelations when their seals were broken. I'd be interested to hear your reasoning for the rest of the riddle too if thats okay with you.

Comment: @dantheflyingman: thanks! Hm. I thought all the lines were pretty self-explanatory, which is why I didn't elaborate.

Comment: +1 for Terry [Pratchett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Read#Top_200_novels_in_the_United_Kingdom) name-drop

Answer (score 2):

Are we

> Humanity or mankind

We sicken at the thought of history

> Mankind looks at the failures of the past

We fight to make our mark on the present.

> It's our goal to leave a legacy and to be known for something great

We hunger to deprive the future.

> As a general species, we don't really care enough to save the natural resources for the future, we want more so we take more

We end everything because it is our nature.

> Proof: extinct creatures, degrading environment, depletion of resources

Sorry for a kind of depressing answer but I think it fits lol

Comment: Good guess! I like your reasoning too but humanity is little too broad and wouldn't apply to the knowledge tag. That, coupled with the word play involved, would hint at a more specific answer.